# java.io.FileNotFoundException Minecraft Mod

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, minecraft-forge

When I try to open the minecraft mod project in intelliJ IDEA I get this error when building the project.

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\tiago.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\minecraft_user_repo\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.19-41.1.0_mapped_official_1.19\forge-1.19-41.1.0_mapped_official_1.19.jar (A opera��o pedida n�o pode ser executada num ficheiro com uma sec��o aberta mapeada pelo utilizador)

I've tried deleting and installing everything again but the error continues.

The IntelliJ output can be seen at https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOmFq.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a jdk version that won't work with your app, try getting jkd 17

https://hosthavoc.com/billing/knowledgebase/306/Setting-up-Forge-for-Java-17.html

Answer (score 0):

The error says that this file hasn't been found:  forge-1.19-41.1.0_mapped_official_1.19.jar, so check if it's there :

> C:\Users\tiago.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\minecraft_user_repo\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.19-41.1.0_mapped_official_1.19\forge-1.19-41.1.0_mapped_official_1.19.jar

if yes, then there is surely an error in your code, show the part of the code where you read the file

Comment: I still don't have any code, I'm trying to create a new project and when building the new project I get this error.

Comment: @cYDOGBI is it possible to have a picture of the error?

Answer (score 0):

There's the print of IntelliJ.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOmFq.jpg

Comment: I've done my research and apparently if you downgrade gradle it might fix your error

Comment: do you have your project on github ?? so i can clone it and view it closely?

Comment: By the way, ae you new to minecraft modding?, is it your first project ? did you follow a tutorial ? please explain a bit more if possible?

Comment: Yes I am new to minecraft modding. https://github.com/cYDOGBI/cY1 I'm watching this tutorial.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpoSy091wYI&list=PLKGarocXCE1HrC60yuTNTGRoZc6hf5Uvl

Comment: thank you very much, sadly didn't have the same problem as you... Check if you have the .gradle folder in C:\Users\tiago\.gradle,  if not it's that you haven't installed jdk and that has been causing your problem. All you need to do is install jdk. If you do have the gradle file check in the path if 1.19-41.1.0_mapped_official_1.19.jar is there!!

Comment: I have the .gradle folder. https://imgur.com/0NL31rV

I have the 1.19-41.1.0_mapped_official_1.19.jar file in the right place. https://imgur.com/ekEQZwe

And it still keeps giving the same error.

Comment: have you installed jdk ? https://www.oracle.com/es/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-windows, here is a link with the installer.. it should work after this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The error was just my antivirus that wouldn't let gradle build.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).